# Замена разделителя путей в редакторе Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, файловые-пути

К сожалению, Visual Studio не умеет обрабатывать адекватно пути с прямым слэшами, т.е. какой-нибудь `C:/filename.cpp` при открытии скажет, что путь невалидный:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И нужно использовать обратный (виндузовый) слэш `\`. Есть и обратная ситуация, когда пути с виндузовыми слэшами нужно вставить в код, но по соглашению код стайла использовать прямые слэши. Это впринципе решается заменой по выделенному тексту, но каждый раз делать вручную неудобно.

Поэтому, хочется научить студию принимать разнонаправленные слэши в путях, а заодно иметь возможность быстрой замены `\` → `/` → `\` в выделенном блоке текста. Что можно для этого использовать?

Главный вопрос в быстрой замене символов в редакторе, но если заодно научить студию принимать любые пути, то вообще шикарно будет.

Comment: Вряд ли это есть в настройках. Нашел только плагин https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexdima.copy-relative-path но его вы и сами, наверное, нашли...

Comment: @Maneken плагин для VScode, у меня же обычная Visual Studio. Но даже в этом случае, я не вижу там задекларированной возможности менять разделитель туда/сюда.

Comment: Остаётся только писать плагин самому, заодно и выяснится реально это или нет. Что точно нереально — создать фичареквест и дождаться его одобрения и исполнения. Они то и баги не лечат годами

Comment: В каком случае у Вас появляется это сообщение об ошибке, надеюсь, это не открытие через диалоговое окно? Для случая с переключением наверно можно было бы использовать регулярки и замену текста в выделеном фрагменте кода.

Comment: @DaniilLoban диалог открытия файла. Замена выделенного фрагмента регуляркой не особо удобна. Вот если бы на хоткей повесить.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а почему-бы и нет, вспомнил punto-switcher может на него можно это возложить)